# Tikz isn't plotting the right function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

Im trying to plot a probability function in tikz, but the line plotted isn't even close to how the function should look. Im new to using latex and I have no idea why this isnt working, unless tikz just cant handle this function.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={Probability(\n,\k) = 1-((\n!)/((\n^(\k))*((\n-
\k)!)));}
]

\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=0:15, samples=2500,
  axis lines=left, xlabel=$k$, ylabel=$y$,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=east},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=north},
  height=10cm, width=15cm,
  xtick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14},
  ytick={0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1},
  enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
  grid = major,
  xmax=15
  ]

\addplot [very thin,cyan!20!black] {Probability(10,x)};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what the function should look like, 
[image: wolfram alpha plot]
And this is what tikz is plotting
[image: latex plot]

I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: You define the function,`Probability` in terms of factorial! What you might not know is that factorial is also defined for non integers -hence your result. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Factorial_of_a_non-integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

answer addresses only `pgfplots` aspect. for drawing (vertical) lines you need to add option `ycomb`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={p(\n,\k) = 1-((\n!)/((\n^(\k))*((\n-\k)!)));}
                    ]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, 
            xlabel=$k$, ylabel=$y$, 
            ylabel style={anchor=south},
            xlabel style={anchor=west},
            ymax=1.2, xmax=15.5,
            domain=0:15, samples=150,
            no markers
                    ]
\addplot+ [ycomb] {p(2,x)}; % <----
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**addendum:**
image with correct settings of your probability function (variables should be integers) is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={p(\n,\k) = 1-((\n!)/((\n^(\k))*((\n-\k)!)));}
                    ]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
            xlabel=$k$, ylabel=$y$,
            ylabel style={anchor=south},
            xlabel style={anchor=west},
            ymax=1.1, xmax=32,      % <-------
            domain=0:30, samples=31,% <-------
%            no markers
                    ]
\addplot+ [ycomb] {p(2,x)};         % <-------
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect thankyou! Do you know why my code was plotting such a strange curve?

Comment: regarding `pgfplots` you not use `ycomb` macro, regarding function: you use far to mach samples and selected function parameters lead to"strange" image. i didn't check definition of your function, however negative probabilities is unlike.

Comment: As Its a probability function of a discrete variable, how would I get it to only plot values at the integers?

Comment: hm, that is math problem ... one way can be increase function domain (for example `domain=0:120)` and select sample number equal to domain (`samples=120`)

Comment: off-topic, but how can a probability function become negative?

Comment: Thanks for your help zarko. It wouldn't be negative as the function is only defined at the integers. At zero and one the function is zero, it's non zero from 2 onwards.

Comment: @John545 If the function is only defined at integers, why do you use 2500 samples in a domain from 0 to 15? `domain=0:15,samples=16`, or `samples at={0,...,15}`.

Comment: That was because I was trying to get it to plot the correct curve, I tried a small number of samples and a large number of samples and neither worked. I'm still very new to learning how to use latex and tikz. Thanks, I'll change the samples. Does anybody know why it is going negative at zero? If you put k=0 into the function it comes out as zero but that isn't in the plot.